# prompting user for geolocation through a modal programmatically without getCurrentPosition()

Tags: javascript, geolocation

```
function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    setCookie('geolocation', latitude+","+longitude, 1);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, null);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API

> "prompt" The "Enable Geolocation" button is hidden, as it isn't needed
> if the user will be prompted to grant permission for Geolocation. The
> Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() function is then run, which prompts
> the user for permission; it runs the revealPosition() function if
> permission is granted (which shows the map), or the positionDenied()
> function if permission is denied (which makes the "Enable Geolocation"
> button appear).

In the mozilla documentation it says that getCurrentPosition prompts the user through a modal to ask for the geolocation permission; however, when I ran the code on mobile, I didn't see it prompt me anything, so I am wondering if getCurrentPosition doesn't prompt the user. Is there a way to prompt the user through a modal if he wants to allow geolocation data to be given to the website?